Weird Scrollbar UI element in programmatically created NSScrollView (objective-c)
i am on macOS, objective-C. Not Swift, not ios.
I have a programmatically created NSScrollView with a nested NSTableView.
The scrollbar shows some kind of square element. This element lies above the scrollbar, but is not visible in the view hierarchy debugger. I want it to not show up.
Here is a video:

Here is a screenshot from the view hierarchy:

Here's the code creating the scrollView and and tableView:
// Create tableView
NSTableView* tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone;
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
tableView.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
tableView.delegate = self.delegate ? self.delegate : weakSelf;
tableView.dataSource = self.delegate ? self.delegate : weakSelf;
tableView.rowHeight = height; // predefined
tableView.intercellSpacing = NSMakeSize(2, 2);
tableView.headerView = [[NSTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 0, CGFLOAT_MIN)];
tableView.columnAutoresizingStyle = NSTableViewUniformColumnAutoresizingStyle;
if (@available(macOS 11.0, *)) {tableView.style = NSTableViewStylePlain;}
self.tableView = tableView;


    
// Create Scroll View
NSScrollView* scrollView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

scrollView.verticalScrollElasticity = NSScrollElasticityAutomatic;

// Setup scrollView
scrollView.drawsBackground = NO;
scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = YES;
scrollView.autohidesScrollers = YES;
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
scrollView.documentView = tableView;
scrollView.scrollerStyle = NSScrollerStyleLegacy; // Must be legacy (!)
scrollView.automaticallyAdjustsContentInsets = NO;
scrollView.contentInsets = insets;
scrollView.scrollerInsets = NSEdgeInsetsMake(-(insets.top), -(insets.left), -(insets.bottom), -(insets.right)); // insets are predefined
self.scrollView = scrollView;

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

Any help appreciated

Where is the header view? Which setting causes the issue? What are you trying to accomplish with the insets and the CGFLOAT_MIN header view?

The manual insets are required cause this is a scrollview inside a bigger outter scrollview (to adjust views). In this case insets are (0,0,0,0). They are not responsible for the "glitch" (already tried).
The headers are not used in my tables. (dont need any sort or drag/drop functions).

@Willeke This took me to the right direction. When a table header isn't needed you just can set it to nil. This removes the glitch. Thank you

When a table header isn't needed you just can set it to nil. This removes the glitch.
Credits to @willeke for pushing me to the right direction
